# Raid 10 performance worse than raid 6

Tags: raid

I'm using a dell DSS 2500 with a PERC 730P raid controller and 12x4TB sata disks under Debian 9.

I had it configured as raid6 but I wanted more write performance so I changed to a raid10 configuration using all 12 disks.

After than, my write performance has dropped from 750MB/s to 450MB/s when testing with dd

dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync

How is that possible?

Comment: What stripe sizes did you configure with?

Comment: 64KB, ADRA,WB, Disk cache enabled